# Visual Studio can't handle errors

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual C# 2010 Express and Visual Basic 2010 Express on my Windows 8 developer preview PC.

Before, there was no problem, both VB and C# work fine.
But today, both VB and C# can't handle errors. I have created a simple application with VB and C#. (.Net framework 4.0) the codes are here:

VB.Net :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Throw New Exception("Hi")
End Sub
```

C# :

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Hi");
    }
```

When I run the program, this dialog appears:

[image]

And after clicking OK, the error dialog shows for a little moments and then program stops quickly. So, I can't even read the error on the error dialog...

So, What is the problem?

EDIT : Visual studio **should** show a exception dialog like this :
[image]

**But** visual studio shows the dialog shown in first image instead of this dialog. So, I can't debug my program.

**EDIT 2 : If I enable break exception when thrown in Exceptions dialog, the problem solves, but at that point, visual studio breaks on EVERY exception , even handled exceptions... I don't want to break on every exception...**

Comment: You sure Win8 Dev Preview didn't get updated? This could have broken something...I mean it is a developer preview and not officially supported.

Comment: @Brad I have checked it right now. no new updates were installed.

Comment: If I had to guess it probably has more to do with Win8 preview than Visual Studio or even you code.  I would try your code on a non-preview machine and see if you get the same error.

Comment: I also have windows 7, it doesn't have this problem. Also I have another developer preview machine. also it doesn't have this problem. and yesterday, this preview machine also had not this problem! this problem might not be from preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting all settings : `MenuBar => Tools => Import and Export Settings => Reset all settings`

If it still doesn't work, run VS as admin and in `Windows XP` compatibility mode.

Comment: I have refreshed my Windows 8, and I have no problems right now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked VS debug settings?  Specifically, under Tools > Options > Debugging > General check the options for when to break on exceptions.

Also, what do you have set under Debug > Exceptions, specifically under the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"?  VS may not break on an exception unless you have told it to do so.

Comment: My debug settings are here : http://4ax.ir/images/vsoptions.png  I think they are correct. and about CLR Exceptions: User-unhandled exceptions have a tick. but if I add a tick to thrown exceptions (All on CLR Exceptions), VS shows the normal error dialog. but the disadvantage is, if that option is enabled, even all handled exceptions are shown for me.

Comment: Please check this : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debugger/archive/2010/05/12/visual-studio-debugger-fails-to-catch-unhandled-exception-for-a-windows-form-or-wpf-application.aspx  Isn't this my problem? if yes, why I hadn't this problem before?